# A Spring-Boot CORS configuration red, but not applied? Access-Control-Allow-Origin is said missing but I gave it

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, cors

My web site on `http://localhost:4200`
is calling a REST service implemented by *Spring Boot* on `http://localhost:9090`.

The REST service is declared that way:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="/cog", name="cog")
@OpenAPIDefinition(info = @Info(title = "Maillage territorial par le Code Officiel Géographique"))
public class COGController {
   @RequestMapping(value = "/communesTriLocale", method=RequestMethod.GET)
   public List<Commune> obtenirCommunesTriParLocale(
      @RequestParam(name="anneeCOG") int anneeCOG, @RequestParam(name="locale") String locale) {
      [...]
   }
}
```

It needs CORS settings, I introduce with a `@Config`:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class CorsConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
   /** Logger. */
   private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CorsConfig.class);

   /** Mapping pour CORS. */
   @Value("${backend.cors.mapping}")
   private String corsMapping;

   /** Origine autorisée pour CORS. */
   @Value("${backend.cors.allowedOrigins:null}")
   private String corsAllowedOrigins;

   /** Méthodes HTTP autorisées pour CORS. */
   @Value("${backend.cors.allowedMethods:null}")
   private String corsAllowedMethods;

   /** Exposed headers pour CORS. */
   @Value("${backend.cors.exposedHeaders:null}")
   private String corsExposedHeaders;

   /**
    * {@inheritDoc}
    */
   @Override
   public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
      CorsRegistration registration = registry.addMapping(this.corsMapping);
      LOGGER.info("Les règles CORS du backend métier autorisent pour pour le mapping {} :", this.corsMapping);

      if (this.corsAllowedOrigins != null) {
         registration.allowedOrigins(this.corsAllowedOrigins);
         LOGGER.info("\t- AllowedOrigins : {}", this.corsAllowedOrigins);
      }

      if (this.corsAllowedMethods != null) {
         registration.allowedMethods(this.corsAllowedMethods);
         LOGGER.info("\t- AllowedMethods : {}", this.corsAllowedMethods);
      }

      if (this.corsExposedHeaders != null) {
         registration.exposedHeaders(this.corsExposedHeaders);
         LOGGER.info("\t- ExposedHeaders : {}", this.corsExposedHeaders);
      }
   }
}
```

Things look OK at the beginning, as with my chosen properties values, *Spring Boot* is logging this, after starting this web server on the port `9090`:

```
INFO Application : Starting Application v0.0.12-SNAPSHOT using Java 17.0.6 on debian with PID 449341 [...]
INFO TomcatWebServer: Tomcat initialized with port(s): 9090 (http)
[...]
INFO CorsConfig : Les règles CORS du backend métier autorisent pour pour le mapping /** :
INFO CorsConfig :         - AllowedOrigins : http://localhost:4200
INFO CorsConfig :         - AllowedMethods : GET,POST,PUT,PATCH,DELETE,OPTIONS
INFO CorsConfig :         - ExposedHeaders : Authorization
```

However, my web request to `http://localhost:9090/cog/communesTriLocale?anneeCOG=2022&locale=fr_FR`, done through an *Angular* web site using *OpenApi* for that, is failing with a `403` HTTP code, and the message:

```
Blocage d’une requête multiorigines (Cross-Origin Request) : 
la politique « Same Origin » ne permet pas de consulter la ressource distante située sur 
http://localhost:9090/cog/communesTriLocale?anneeCOG=2022&locale=fr_FR. 
Raison : l’en-tête CORS « Access-Control-Allow-Origin » est manquant. Code d’état : 403.
```

The browser exposing this exchange on the Network debug tab (coming from the Browser):

for request header:

```http
GET /cog/communesTriLocale?anneeCOG=2022&locale=fr_FR HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:9090
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:102.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/102.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: fr,fr-FR;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Origin: http://localhost:4200
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://localhost:4200/
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
```

for response header:

```http
HTTP/1.1 403 
Vary: Origin, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Mon, 12 Jun 2023 06:00:33 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=60
Connection: keep-alive
```

Or, if I do a curl from a command line, I'm receiving this:

```http
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 9090 (#0)
> GET /cog/communesTriLocale?anneeCOG=2022&locale=fr_FR HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:9090
> User-Agent: curl/7.74.0
> Accept: */*
```

```http
< HTTP/1.1 200 
< Vary: Origin
< Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
< Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
< Content-Type: application/json
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Date: Mon, 12 Jun 2023 06:13:38 GMT
```

I have searched in my code for parasite `@CrossConfig` wrote elsewhere, or something else that could mislead *Spring Boot* and make it reconfigure something behind the scene, but found none.

---

Edit: responding to your question, @jub0bs, the GET request is emitted with *OpenApi* generated code, by *Angular*:

```
this.cogService.obtenirCommunesTriParLocale(this.anneeCOG, this.locale).subscribe(data => {
   this.communes = data;

   this.communes.forEach(commune => {
      this.communesMap.set(commune.codeCommune, commune);
   });
});
```

It leads it to that generated method:

```
public obtenirCommunesTriParLocale(anneeCOG: number, locale: string, observe?: 'body', reportProgress?: boolean, options?: {httpHeaderAccept?: '*/*'}): Observable<Array<Commune>>;
public obtenirCommunesTriParLocale(anneeCOG: number, locale: string, observe?: 'response', reportProgress?: boolean, options?: {httpHeaderAccept?: '*/*'}): Observable<HttpResponse<Array<Commune>>>;
public obtenirCommunesTriParLocale(anneeCOG: number, locale: string, observe?: 'events', reportProgress?: boolean, options?: {httpHeaderAccept?: '*/*'}): Observable<HttpEvent<Array<Commune>>>;
public obtenirCommunesTriParLocale(anneeCOG: number, locale: string, observe: any = 'body', reportProgress: boolean = false, options?: {httpHeaderAccept?: '*/*'}): Observable<any> {
    if (anneeCOG === null || anneeCOG === undefined) {
        throw new Error('Required parameter anneeCOG was null or undefined when calling obtenirCommunesTriParLocale.');
    }
    if (locale === null || locale === undefined) {
        throw new Error('Required parameter locale was null or undefined when calling obtenirCommunesTriParLocale.');
    }

    let queryParameters = new HttpParams({encoder: this.encoder});
    if (anneeCOG !== undefined && anneeCOG !== null) {
      queryParameters = this.addToHttpParams(queryParameters,
        <any>anneeCOG, 'anneeCOG');
    }
    if (locale !== undefined && locale !== null) {
      queryParameters = this.addToHttpParams(queryParameters,
        <any>locale, 'locale');
    }

    let headers = this.defaultHeaders;

    let httpHeaderAcceptSelected: string | undefined = options && options.httpHeaderAccept;
    if (httpHeaderAcceptSelected === undefined) {
        // to determine the Accept header
        const httpHeaderAccepts: string[] = [
               '*/*'
        ];
        httpHeaderAcceptSelected = this.configuration.selectHeaderAccept(httpHeaderAccepts);
    }
    if (httpHeaderAcceptSelected !== undefined) {
        headers = headers.set('Accept', httpHeaderAcceptSelected);
    }


    let responseType: 'text' | 'json' = 'json';
    if(httpHeaderAcceptSelected && httpHeaderAcceptSelected.startsWith('text')) {
        responseType = 'text';
    }

    return this.httpClient.get<Array<Commune>>(`${this.configuration.basePath}/cog/communesTriLocale`,
    {
       params: queryParameters,
       responseType: <any>responseType,
       withCredentials: this.configuration.withCredentials,
       headers: headers,
       observe: observe,
       reportProgress: reportProgress
     }
  );
}
```

If I put a breakpoint at the level of the line calling `this.httpClient.get`, I have this state:

[image]

From http.get to its ErrorHandler, I have no way to stop its running to another interesting point: debugger goes straight forward, and ends with in `ErrorHandler` class with this debug state:

[image]

What is a preflight in CORS? That notion of preflight, in general, is unknown to me. But looks something important to know.

---

Why is `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` said missing?

It looks like my *Spring Boot* `@Config` isn't taken into account.
Or is it something else that is happening?

---

As @ZahidKhan suggested and I've experienced, if I comment my `CorsConfig` `@Config` class, and choose to add to my REST controller this annotation instead:

```java
@CrossOrigin(origins = {"http://localhost:8080", "http://localhost:4200", 
    "http://localhost:9090", "http://localhost:9091"})
```

It works. So one way or another, the configuration `CorsConfig` should find a way to work too.

Comment: What does your `GET` request look like? Is it preflighted? If so, what does the preflight request look like?

Comment: @jub0bs Thanks for your help! I've added a debug session experienced from client side (Angular) in my question.

Comment: Have you tried using @CrossOrigin

Comment: About preflight, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request

Comment: Also, screenshots of the relevant request(s) in your browser's Network tab would be more useful.

Comment: @ZahidKhan I saw that exchanging `@CorsConfig` implementation by `@CrossOrigin(origins={"http://localhost:4200", "http://localhost:8080"...}` on the top of the REST controller seems to solve the issue. I'm investingating to ensure this, everywhere. But then, this would tend to confirm that what is inside my `@Config` annotated class isn't taken into account.

Comment: @jub0bs I'll try to get these screenshot later (I'm not in front of my computer, yet)

Comment: @jub0bs I've checked. The Network tab content of my browser is dumped as Request and Reponse at the beginning of my question. But I don't know of to get the preflight request if some has been emitted. Neither on _Firefox_ or _Chrome_ I see where to go to dump it.